# How to combine two elements in the same arrays?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that contains as such

```
         String[][] twodarray = { { "grey", "value1", "beta"  },
                                 { "r", "name", "gender" , "value", "Female"  },
                                { "r", "name", "gender", "value", "Male" },
                                { "r", "name", "exp", "value", "1" },
                                { "r", "name", "exp", "value", "2"  }, 
                                { "red", "value1", "alpha"  },
                                { "blue", "value2", "alpha"  }, 
                        };
```

My goal is when there are 2 or more elements [a][0] and [a][2] are the same, it will group together and combine the elements as one.

For example,
[1][0] and [2][0], r and
[1][2] and [2][2], gender 
are the same.

Thus, it will combine into one as shown below.

`{ "r", "name", "gender" , "value", "Female", "Male" },`

Thus, my desired output is as follow

```
      final output:
          results = { { "grey", "value1", "beta"  },
                    { "r", "name", "gender" , "value", "Female", "Male" },
                    { "r", "name", "exp", "value", "1", "2"  }, 
                    { "red", "value1", "alpha"  },
                    { "blue", "value2", "alpha"  }, 
                  };
```

What I have is as follow

```
                for (int a=0; a < twodarray.length-1; a++)
                {
                    if ((twodarray[a][0] == twodarray[a+1][0]) && (twodarray[a][2] == twodarray[a+1][2]))
                }
    }
```

My question is how can I combine the array as such?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have collected the rows into a `Map<List<String>, List<String>>` which groups final values (the last String) by the prefix (every String other than the last String). Then I collected the map entries back into a 2d String array format:

```
package samplejava;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SampleJava {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] twodarray = { { "grey", "value1", "beta"  },
                                { "r", "name", "gender" , "value", "Female"  },
                                { "r", "name", "gender", "value", "Male" },
                                { "r", "name", "exp", "value", "1" },
                                { "r", "name", "exp", "value", "2"  }, 
                                { "red", "value1", "alpha"  },
                                { "blue", "value2", "alpha"  }, 
                        };
    Map<List<String>, List<String>> groups;
    groups = Arrays.stream(twodarray).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            (String[] item)-> Arrays.asList(item).subList(0, item.length - 1),
            Collectors.mapping(
                    (String[] item)-> item[item.length - 1],
                    Collectors.toList())));
    String[][] result = groups.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> Stream.concat(entry.getKey().stream(),
                                        entry.getValue().stream())
                    .toArray(String[]::new))
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
    for(String[] row: result) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
}
```

This method, however, does not preserve the original order of items. But you did not say that was necessary.

Comment: There is Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>

Comment: @ESal are you sure? it compiles and runs fine for me. I am using jdk 1.8 and netbeans IDE 8.2

Comment: Yes, I am using jdk 1.8 and eclipse. Just want to make sure you imported `import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;` ?

Comment: @ESal there should be a way to automatically fix the required imports. in NetBeans it is Ctrl+Shift+I. Anyways, I included the entire file now.

Comment: It works now. Thanks! However, if I have `{ "r", "id", "1", "name", "gender" , "value", "Female"  }, { "r", "id", "2", "name", "gender", "value", "Male" },` . It wont work anymore. Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: @ESal you didn't explain how such a thing should merge. what happens to the 1 and the 2? Please update your original question with this new information.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error, because on the last step of the cycle, while a = 6, you try to get 7th element of the array (when `twodarray[a+1][0]`), which, obvious don't exist. You should do cycle from 0 to a.length - 1, to have your index in bound. 
`for (int a=0; a < twodarray.length - 1; a++)`

Comment: Thanks! Half of the question is answered :)